# How to programmatically load font extension at runtime?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I know about the `jasperreports_extension.properties` and how to put in into classpath to make fonts available to jasper reports.

I want to load them fonts dynamically while runtime, without them being available on the classpath at application startup.

Is there a API in Jasper I can use, and if yes, how?
If possible, I would prefer an answer for Jasper 5.x.

Comment: If you like to load jar this is related [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can programmatically register font extensions and other extension types by creating a `JasperReportsContext` instance (such as `SimpleJasperReportsContext`), adding the extensions to the context object and then using it when filling and exporting reports.

The code would look something like this:

```
//create the context object and the font extension
SimpleJasperReportsContext jasperReportsContext = new SimpleJasperReportsContext();

SimpleFontFamily fontFamily = new SimpleFontFamily(jasperReportsContext);
fontFamily.setName("family name");//to be used in reports as fontName
fontFamily.setPdfEmbedded(true);
fontFamily.setPdfEncoding("Identity-H");

SimpleFontFace regular = new SimpleFontFace(jasperReportsContext);
regular.setTtf("font ttf path");
fontFamily.setNormalFace(regular);

jasperReportsContext.setExtensions(FontFamily.class, Arrays.asList(fontFamily));

//use the context when filling and exporting reports
//note that there are variations here depending on the API you use for filling and exporting
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.getInstance(jasperReportsContext).fill(jasperReport, params);
...
JasperExportManager.getInstance(jasperReportsContext).exportToPdf(jasperPrint);
...
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter(jasperReportsContext);
```